# Which component can compose an Android application?

Tags: android

There are four types of app components: Activity, Service, Broadcast Receiver and Content Providers. I know that Activity and Service component can compose an Android application. How about other two? Any documents or papers I can reference?

Comment: The only reason that a component present in Android API is that it can be used in Android application

Comment: `Any documents or papers I can reference?` There you go https://developer.android.com/.

Comment: I mean that which component can compose a single application. The apk can only contain an Activity component without other 3. Same as Service. But, how about Broadcast Receiver and Content Provider?

Comment: I think that you could try and check it by yourself much faster than waiting for somebody to answer.

Comment: I need an official answer. I need documents I can reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Broadcast** is also needed when you really need your app to register with broadcast service. Like service you don't need that all the time in your app. If you have a code which will execute at any particular event of the mobile phone, here comes the Broadcast receiver.
You can find the reference for **Broadcast Receiver** [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics) is the detailed info about **Content Provider**

Comment: You did get my point. I mean if I want to build a dead simple apk, which component will be enough? An apk with one activity is ok. An apk with one service is ok. How about the others?

Comment: simply activity is enough to make an apk and no need service,Broadcast Receiver and Content Providers.